# TypeError: unbound method check() must be called with Signature instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python, django

I am upgrading an existing Django application from 1.3 to 1.11, most things are working fine and now trying to get Celery working. I got some unknown column errors related to Celery so I figured I need to run migrations. However running ./manage.py check or ./manage.py makemigrations gives me the error in the title and I have not been able to fix this. It seems to be coming from Django's code and not my application - here is the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 7, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/var/www/caretaker/www/production/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
TypeError: unbound method check() must be called with Signature instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I had to upgrade my manage.py which now contains the following (running just ./manage.py brings up the list of commands so it seems to be working):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "settings_production_ritn")
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

pip freeze:

```
amqp==1.4.9
amqplib==1.0.2
anyjson==0.3.3
asn1crypto==0.22.0
bcrypt==3.1.3
billiard==3.3.0.23
celery==3.1.25
cffi==1.10.0
cryptography==1.9
Django==1.11.3
django-celery==3.2.1
django-countries==4.6.1
django-debug-toolbar==1.4
django-kombu==0.9.4
django-localflavor==1.5.2
django-picklefield==1.0.0
django-signature==0.3.1
enum34==1.1.6
Fabric==1.13.2
idna==2.5
importlib==1.0.4
ipaddress==1.0.18
kombu==3.0.37
lxml==3.8.0
M2Crypto==0.26.0
MySQL-python==1.2.5
odict==1.6.2
paramiko==2.2.1
pyasn1==0.2.3
pycparser==2.18
pycrypto==2.6.1
PyNaCl==1.1.2
pyparsing==1.5.7
python-dateutil==1.5
pytz==2017.2
PyYAML==3.12
six==1.10.0
soaplib==1.0.0
sqlparse==0.2.3
typing==3.6.1
vine==1.1.4
virtualenv==15.1.0
```

Things I have verified so far:

- I am running under a virtualenv which is activated before running the commands
- both python versions on the system and the virtualenv are the same 2.7.5
- the application itself seems to work fine with the new Django through WSGI so I suspect it is something to do with running via the command line

Any help or pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your `Signature` model has a `check` method, which clashes with the [system check framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/checks/#field-model-manager-and-database-checks) introduced in Django 1.7.

Rename the `Signature.check` method to something else, and remember to update any code that calls it.

It appears that the `Signature` model may be from [django-signature](https://github.com/bearstech/django-signature), which does not appear to have been updated in years. You may have to fork the package, or look for an alternative.